# For a Banach space $X$, can we find a reflexive (or weakly sequentially complete) space $Y$ such that $X\subset Y$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It could be a naive question. Probably, it is not true.
However, this question makes sense in the setting of function spaces.
For example, for $L_\infty (0,1)$, we have $L_p(0,1)\supset L_\infty (0,1)$
and $L_p(0,1)$ is reflexive when $p>1$.
On the other hand, $L_1(0,1)$ itself is weakly sequentially complete and any rearrangement-invariant function spaces on $(0,1)$ is a subset of $L_1(0,1)$.

I am wondering whether we have such a result in the setting of general Banach spaces.

BTW: Davis, Figiel, Johnson and Pełczyński's construction gives us a smaller reflexive space.

Comment: What do you mean by $X \subset Y$? The existence of a continuous linear injection from $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: If you mean that X is a (topological) subspace of Y, then this is true iff X itself is reflexive, for any closed subspace of a reflexive Banach space is reflexive

Comment: The given example $L^\infty(0,1) \subset L^p(0,1)$ seems to indicate that one wants a continuous inclusion.

Comment: Just a trivial remark which might be helpful.  If $X$ is separable, then it embeds isometrically into $C([0 1])$ and so the result holds (take the Lebesgue $L^2$-space).  This can clearly be extended but Ì haven't checked whether to any Banach  space (after embedding into a $C(K)$).

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Yes, I am talking about continuous linear injections.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I am talking about the continous linear injections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact scattered space and $X=C(K)$ the space of continuous functions on $K$. We want to show that there is no injective bounded linear $T:X\to Y$ into a weakly sequentially complete (w.s.c.) Banach space $Y$ if $K$ has *large*(see below) cardinality.

Let $T:X\to Y$ be as above. $C(K)$ has Pelczynski property (V) and $Y$ is w.s.c., so $T$ is weakly compact. Since $C(K)$ has Dunford-Pettis property, then $T$ is completely continuous. Lastly $C(K)$ contains no copy of $\ell^1$ since $K$ is scattered. Thus, $T$ is compact.

Since $T$ is compact, its range $T(X)$ is separable, so $card(T(X))\leq\mathfrak{c}=card(\mathbb{R})$. $T$ is injective, so $card(X)=card(T(X))$. Together, we have
$$ card(K)\leq card(X)=card(T(X))\leq\mathfrak{c}.$$
However, this leads to a contradiction when $card(K)>\mathfrak{c}$. For example, take $K=[0,\alpha]$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ with the order topology, where the cardinality of $\alpha$ is strictly greater than $\mathfrak{c}$.

---

Note (2023-02-18): Following the footsteps in this post, we can actually make a slightly more general statement. If $X$ is a Banach space with property (V), $X^*$ has Schur property, and $card(X)>\mathfrak{c}$, then there exists no injective bounded $T:X\to Y$ into a w.s.c. $Y$.

Comment: A separable metric space can have cardinality the continuum, and the continuum is larger than $\aleph_1$ in some models of set theory.

Comment: @BillJohnson  Professor Johnson, thank you truly for your comment. My limited knowledge of the set theory is mostly bounded by an undergraduate course from 20+ years ago. I think I must have assumed the continuum hypothesis with ZFC for $\aleph_1=card(\mathbb{R})$. I edit my post to fix my oversight.

Comment: @OnurOktay: regarding Bill's comment, your proof works if you just replace every instance of $\aleph_1$ by $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: (However, it **is** actually true that there is no continuous linear injective map from $c_0(\aleph_1)$ into a wsc space.)

Comment: @PhilipBrooker Professor Brooker, at the time I edited the post, I didn't know (until recently) if there existed an ordinal $\alpha$ (I use for the example above) with cardinality strictly greater than $\mathfrak{c}$ without CH in ZF. Actually, aside from $K=[0,\alpha]$, I could have picked any other compact scattered $K$ with $card(K)>\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @OnurOktay very nice and useful proof! I like it very much. Thank you!

Comment: To show that $c_0(\aleph_1)$ does not admit a continuous linear injection into a wsc space, first note that $c_0(\aleph_1)$ is isomorphic to $C(K)$, where $K$ is the one point compactification of a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$, and so the first two paragraphs of @OnurOktay's answer show that every continuous linear operator from $c_0(\aleph_1)$ to a wsc space has separable range. Since every separable Banach space $Z$ admits a continuous linear injection into $L_2[0,1]$ (embed $Z$ in $C[0,1]$, then take the inclusion $C[0,1]\hookrightarrow L_2[0,1]$), it suffices to show that $c_0(\aleph_1)$

Comment: ... does not admit a continuous linear injection into $L_2[0,1]$. That this is true was essentially established in the paper [A Banach space that cannot be made into a BIP space](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/banach-space-that-cannot-be-made-into-a-bip-space/B1C8A967F966F2E4FD07D1D320979606) by P. A. Olagunju. (Olagunji proves that $\ell_\infty(\aleph_1)$ does not admit a continuous linear embedding into a Hilbert space using a cardinality argument, but the same argument works for $c_0(\aleph_1)$ too.)

Comment: @OnurOktay Nice answer, by the way!

Comment: @PhilipBrooker Thanks for the detailed explanation, I couldn't see this connection myself. The keywords $c_0(\aleph_1)$ and injective bounded maps put together is perhaps a reminder of the renorming theory. As far as I could remember, the book by Deville, Godefroy, and Zizler is a treatise on the subject, in which there's a subsection about the renormings of $c_0(\Gamma)$. It is an old result by Day that $c_0(\Gamma)$ admits a strictly convex equivalent norm. However, it doesn't admit a URED norm (pls. see the book), and

Comment: ... every space $X$ for which $\exists T:X\to H$ injective into a Hilbert space $H$ admit an equivalent URED norm (Thm 2.6.8). This is just an alternative point of view, and perhaps an expert in the subject can draw more general conclusions from the book by Deville, Godefroy, and Zizler, especially about the scattered $C(K)$ spaces.